# wxPython problems with StaticText RightAlign

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm using a wx statictext class to display readings that will be updated every second. I want the readings to be right aligned in the grid bag sizer. When I begin my program to start displaying values, the values are left aligned, but if I go from maximize window -> minimize window -OR- minimize window -> maximize window, the readings align and continue to stay re-aligned. I've set the `wx.ALIGN_RIGHT` for the static text style, and flag `wx.ALIGN_RIGHT` when adding it to the grid bag sizer. I'm not sure why I need to do a window size change before the values have the correct alignment. When I adjust the size of the windows via the edges the values stay wrongly aligned, it is only when it is maximized/minimized.

```
static_text_reading[i] = wx.StaticText(self,
    wx.ID_ANY, DEFAULT_START_TEXT,
    style = wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)

main_gbs = wx.GridBagSizer( 0, 0 )

main_gbs.Add(static_text_reading[i], 
             pos=(1,i+1),
             flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT,
             border=self.border)

topSizer.Add(main_gbs, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, self.border)
```

Comment: did you call Layout() at the end of the function?

Comment: @Igor Layout() seemed to do the trick, thank you. Is there a way to re-layout a single wx module instead of the whole panel? I have multiple readings and having to re-layout everything constantly causes flicker on the GUI. I want to re-layout only changed readings.

Comment: you can try calling Layout() on the sizer, but I'm not sure it will work. Can you post the whole function where you create the elements?